# VB.NET download html code tables

Tags: html, vb.net, search, html-table, vb.net-2010

I'm pretty new to vb.net and I have a big problem with a software I'm creating for my own use.

**1. Background:**

I have code in my software that downloads the source code of a webpage into a .txt file and filters out information it's looking for. For normal HTML code this works fine.

---

**2. Problem:**

The problem is when I can't target specific parameters in the HTML code because they're too vague.

---

**3. Examples:**

I can download this kind of unique HTML code and pass the variable (Brown in this case) to Strings in my software because it's on the same line of code making it unique:

```
<div class="Performer_DataLabel">Hair Color:</div> Brown</div>
```

However I want to know how to search a specific table and its rows and cells (like this one below showing the code for 1 row and the 2 cells I'm interested in):

```
1.  <tr>
2.      <td class="paramname">
3.         <b>Hair Color:</b>
4.      </td>
5.      <td class="paramvalue">
6.          Brown&nbsp;
7.      </td>
8.  </tr>
```

The thing is that as you can see, "Hair Color:" can be any variable like "Eye Color" or "Height" and "Brown" can be any answer to that question. There's not enough unique code in these tables, rows or cells to target those lines of code specifically like when they're written on a single line.

---

**4. I want:**

To be able to search and target "Hair Color" in HTML code tables like in the above example  and search/target its answer (Brown in this case) in its adjacent cell and pass it into a String variable (I will always know that I'm looking for like "Hair Color" but I will never know beforehand the answer to the Hair Color question and that answer variable is what I want to find).

---

**5. Conclusion:**

What VB.NET code can I use to:

1) Search/target HTML code tables that contains words like "Hair Color" or "Eye Color".

2) Search/target their answer variables regardless of what they are. (Some questions may have a long range of possible answers, so an IF or SELECT CASE statement to predict/compare them right now is not an option)

3) Pass the answer to a String in my software.

---

**6. Note**

The question (Hair Color), regardless of how many hundreds of lines the full source code is, is always on the same line within the row of the table (line 3).

The answer is also always on the same line (line 6) in the row of the table.

However the question rows themselves are not always on the in the same place of the table.

Comment: Where is the HTML coming from? You say it is not uniform in structure - well, that's makes it impossible to give a solution. Data in HTML is **not** uniformly structured and you can't query it in a uniform manner.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Is it possible to target say "Hair Color" in the source code if it indeed was unique (for arguments sake) and then based on that target always simply jump down 3 lines to target what ever is at that line?

Comment: You can _find_ that string in the HTML source, but there is no way to know in what structure it will be held without examining the source. In particular it will not give you a direct way to access other data.

Comment: These comments assume that data source is from all over the Internet - if you have one specific source that structures all its HTML is the same way, that's a different matter.

Comment: The source in my case is always the same website for every search and the data is always structured the same. Because of the difficulty of getting around the situation I will be tailoring the searches for every website that is added.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make use of [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), it's very useful to parse HTML (even not valid one). You need to download it and add to references of your project, add `Imports HtmlAgilityPack` at the begining of your code file. Here is the code to solve your problem after that:

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument, strAnswer As String
        document.Load("C:\tmp\1.html")
        For Each td As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
            If td.InnerText.IndexOf("Hair Color") <> -1 Then
                strAnswer = next_td(td).InnerText
                MsgBox(strAnswer)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Function next_td(td As HtmlNode) As HtmlNode
      Try
        If td.NextSibling.Name = "td" Then
            Return td.NextSibling
        Else
            Return next_td(td.NextSibling)
        End If
       Catch
       Throw New Exception("Last <td> in document reached")
       End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: I just downloaded HTML Agility Pack and added it as a reference to my project, the code doesn't give errors excep for HtmlDocument and I receive the following error when trying to build: **Error 1 'HtmlDocument' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'HtmlAgilityPack, System.Windows.Forms'.**

Comment: Oh, I wasn't using Windows.Forms in my test project. Replace `Dim document As New HtmlDocument` with `Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`

Comment: My apologies for not mentioning that in my Question. I replaced it with what you mentioned and it cleared that error. But now Visual Studio 2010 complains on _For Each td As HtmlNode In_  **document.Descendants** _("td")_ and says **'Descendants' is not a member of 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument'**.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, It should be `document.DocumentNode`, not just `document`, because document is obviously not a node. I corrected the code in the answer to work.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I've cleared the errors but now I've run into another problem. The updated code `document.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")` only targets the very first occurance of `<td>` in the webpage source code, then it simply settles for that and declares `td.InnerText.IndexOf("Hair Color") <> -1 Then` as False and exists the loop. How do I refine the search to find `Hair Color`?

Comment: Is "hair color" in the text in the same case as in your node? Also I found that my code doesn't work if <td> doesn't immediately follow </td> of "Hair Color" cell (that's behaviour of "NextSibling", though I haven't expected it. So I had to write a recursive function, which finds really next "<td>" element (see the code in my answer)